# Getting an error for a module that I definitely imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

```
import pyinputplus as pyip

while True:
    prompt='Want to know how to keep an idiot busy for hours?\n'
    response=pyip.inputYesNo(prompt)
    if response=='no':
        break
    print('Thank you. Have a nice day.')
```

When I run my above code , I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\XXXXXX\mu_code\idiot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyinputplus as pyip
  File "c:\users\XXXXXX\mu_code\pyinputplus\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pysimplevalidate as pysv # type: ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysimplevalidate'
```

I cannot figure it out. The module is definitely installed. I've even moved it from the folder it was originally installed in to the mu folder where the py file is saved. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the response to `pip install pyinputplus`?

Comment: and `pysimplevalidate`?

Comment: are you asking if I enter the above in the command line?

Comment: @MdCAL12 The error itself says that the module is not installed. I'd suggest, reconfirming that. If not, make sure that your module is accessible in your environment.

Comment: The module is definitely installed. Could you explain more by what you mean "accessible in your environment"? I've added the modules folder to where the py file is being saved, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @MdCAL12 To clarify, the error is saying `pysimplevalidate` is not installed. What is the output of `pip install pysimplevalidate`? If you didn't install it via `pip`, how did you install it exactly, and are you sure it's installed correctly?

Comment: Hi, @MdCAL12, could you tell us how you run the code here? For example, do you run it with `python` at the command line, or do you use an IDE? Also, what have you done to install the package `pysimplevalidate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ModuleError says that you do not have `pysimplevalidate` installed.

Using the *same* `python` executable as you are using to run your script (idiot.py), run

```
python -m pip install pysimplevalidate
```

or, even more bullet-proof:

```
<path_to_python.exe> -m pip install pysimplevalidate
```

---

If you are not sure what python executable the script is using, you can check it with

```
# put this on top of your script
import sys
print(sys.executable) # will print C:\path\to\python.exe
```